# Solve trigonometric equation $\tan x = \arctan x$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

What are the non-trivial solutions of
$$\tan x = \arctan x$$

Can these solutions be expressed e.g. in terms of $\pi$ or in radicals?
I mean are they some "nice" numbers?

E.g. do we know if these solutions are irrational, or rational, some rational multiple of $\pi$, or say something like e.g. $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{7}$?

What about $\cot x = \text{arccot} (x)$? I became curious about these problems after graphing the four functions.

Comment: Are you asking about $\cot$ or $\tan^{-1}$.... big difference!!

Comment: So you are asking when does $\tan (\tan x) = x$?

Comment: Or are you asking with $\frac {\sin x}{\cos x} = \frac {\cos x}{\sin x}$?  (Which makes the the question about $\cot$ equivalent)

Comment: @fleablood Yes, this was what I was asking about. Not sure what $tan^{-1}(x)$ means in the English math literature.

Comment: It's ambiguous.  $f^{-1}(x)$ is usually taken to mean the functional inverse of $f$.  However as $(f(x))^k=f(x)\cdot f(x)\cdot...\cdot f(x)$ is frequently written in shorthand as $f^k(x)$, $f^{-1}(x)$ can naively mistaken to mean $\frac 1{f(x)}$.  And sadly many elementary students get the mistaken idea that it must follow that both $[f^{-1}](x)=\frac 1{f(x)}$.  As we have perfectly good terms $\arctan(x)=(tan^{-1})(x)$ and because we so often refer to powers of trig functions (how many times do we write $\sin^2 x+cos^2 x=1$) its best to use $\arctan$.  It's completely unambiguous.

Comment: OK, right. In the same way, it's ambiguous in my language too. That's why I don't like it. So I used $arctan$, I think (or at least so I intended) in my question. But then my question got edited.

Comment: Anyway, now I edited my question so that it reads just as I meant it.

Answer (score 0):

In the range $[0, 2 \pi]$ the graph shows two solutions, $x =0$ and $x \approx 4$:

[image]

and a "closeup":

[image]

and numerical methods give $x = 4.06759.$

Comment: I was asking exactly about non numerical approaches, I was looking for analytical ones.

Comment: Nowhere in your question did you ask for non-numerical approaches.

Comment: Well, I was asking if we have some "nice" solution(s). And... if we know if the solution(s) are rational/irrational etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The solutions can not be expressed in elementary functional values. But, approximate analytic solutions are available.

There are infinite number of roots as $\tan^{-1}x$ cuts across the periodic function $\tan x$. Note that $\tan^{-1}x$ approaches $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$, which  approximately matches $\tan\left( \frac{\pi}{3}+n\pi\right)$. Therefore, we may assume all positive roots $r_n=\frac{\pi}{3}+n\pi + \delta_n$ and expand the equation

$$\tan x=\tan^{-1}x$$

around $s_n=\frac{\pi}{3}+n\pi$ as follows,

$$\tan s_n + \sec^2 s_n\delta_n
= \tan^{-1}s_n + \frac{ \delta_n}{1+s_n^2} $$

which leads to the approximate roots $r_n = s_n + \delta_n$,

$$r_n = s_n -(\sqrt 3 - \tan^{-1}s_n)
\frac{1+s_n^2}{3+4s_n^2 }$$

For illustration, the first a few roots are listed below with the exact solutions in parentheses.

$$r_1 = 4.088 \>(4.068) $$
$$r_2 = 7.256 \>(7.245) $$
$$r_3 = 10.408 \> (10.400) $$
$$...$$

For completeness, $r_0 = 0$ is a special root and the negative roots are just the mirror images of the positive ones due to symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

To have some rather good approximations, considering that you look for the zero's of function
$$f(x)=\tan (x)-\tan ^{-1}(x)$$ Perform **one** single iteration of Newton method with $x_0=\frac \pi 3+n \pi=t$ (as @Quanto showed$ to get the *estimate*
$$x_1=t+\frac{2 \left(t^2+1\right) \cos (t) \left(\cos (t) \tan ^{-1}(t)-\sin
   (t)\right)}{2 t^2-\cos (2 t)+1}$$ Doing the same with Halley method
$$x_1=t+\frac{\left(t^2+1\right) \left(\tan ^{-1}(t)-\tan (t)\right)
   \left(\left(t^2+1\right) \sec ^2(t)-1\right)}{\left(t^4-1\right) \sec ^2(t)+\tan
   ^{-1}(t) \left(\left(t^2+1\right)^2 \tan (t) \sec ^2(t)+t\right)-t \tan (t)+1}$$

You could do the same with Householder method.

For the first roots, some results

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}n & \text{Newton} & \text{Halley}& \text{Householder}  & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 4.088538670 & 4.067078038 & 4.067589392 &  4.067588866 \\
 2 & 7.255833334 & 7.244717199 & 7.244917158 &  7.244916979 \\
 3 & 10.40771565 & 10.39964606 & 10.39976940 &  10.39976930 \\
 4 & 13.55484465 & 13.54818508 & 13.54827702 &  13.54827695 \\
 5 & 16.69989506 & 16.69403891 & 16.69411435 &  16.69411429 \\
 6 & 19.84385223 & 19.83851226 & 19.83857769 &  19.83857764 \\
 7 & 22.98716378 & 22.98218244 & 22.98224120 &  22.98224116 \\
 8 & 26.13006234 & 26.12534424 & 26.12539826 &  26.12539822 \\
 9 & 29.27268077 & 29.26816391 & 29.26821440 &  29.26821437 \\
 10 & 32.41510047 & 32.41074234 & 32.41079012 &  32.41079008
\end{array}
\right)$$